# Need Flash popup to redirect parent

Tags: php, flash

I'm working on a project with a Flash object I have no control over, though I can get changes made by the developer.  What needs to happen is for the Flash object to POST a value to a php file on my server, and upon a successful result, redirect the *parent* window to a new url, and then close the popup.

It's POSTing correctly, but the redirect won't go to the parent.

Right now, we have this javascript happening in the Flash, which works with straight HTML:

```
opener.location='view_cart.php';
self.close();
```

And it's just closing the window without a redirect.

Any suggestions?

I should add - just a redirect was working fine, but in the Flash window, which is not what we want.

Comment: Is the redirect script in the HTML/JS file and you called it from Flash using `ExternalInterface`?

Comment: The Javascript is embedded in the Flash, as far as I know

Comment: Try to put the JS function in HTML/JS file and Flash call it from `ExternalInterface`. Also try calling those function directly from JS to see if the JS code works or not.

Comment: Thanks, Andy.  The JavaScript works on its own.  I'm trying to get the Flash dev to update the file for me so I can try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andy Li indicated in the comments to the question, ExternalInterface, with a JavaScript function to do what we wanted, was the solution.